# 180º stereoscopic spherical video rotation

Tags: projection, virtual-reality, stereo-3d

I'm coding a VR player from the ground as it's for the PS VR and I'm facing a problem.

Everithing seemed ok until I added the input from the HMD, at first I was using the mouse to rotate the view and everything was ok, the projection was right, but as the HMD has three axes, yaw pitch and roll, when the roll has been introduced I noticed the projections match no more when roll is not zero.

The rotation is correct, if I use a monoscopic video everithing looks ok. Thinking about it makes sense, as you roll your head, in a 3d environment each eye looks at a different point in the space and the projections start to diverge. If the projection were a plane, displacing each eye projection on the X axis (the camera is still, the projection is what rotates, the sphere or plane) inwards or outwards according to the roll would compensate this, but as it's an sphere I have no idea on how to compensate this.

So the question, how can be compensated the projections roll to make them converge again?